# What are the criteria for evaluating the contenders for Quran challange?

Tags: quran, arabic

The Quran challenges doubters to produce something like it. This is known as the [Quran challenge.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge_of_the_Quran)

For example, in [2/23](https://quran.com/2/23), it says, to doubters, to produce a chapter (surah) like one of those in the Quran.

> And if you are in doubt about what We have revealed to Our servant,
> then produce a sûrah like it and call your helpers other than Allah,
> if what you say is true.

Let's say someone takes up this challenge, and produces a surah. How will this surah be evaluated? Did either the scholars, or the scripture (Quran, or ahadith), establish any criteria to evaluate the contenders of the Quran challange?